# Code is saving separate text file, can we use pandas.dataframe() to save in excel in neat and clean format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Python code is saving the separate text file, can we use pandas.dataframe() to save in excel in a neat and clean format. i tried pandas but my excel file is is incorrect format they are messy !

```
import datetime
import time
from kiteconnect import KiteConnect

tdelta0=datetime.timedelta(days=30)
tdelta=datetime.timedelta(days=29)

ak='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
asecret='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

kite = KiteConnect(api_key=ak)
request_tkn = input("[*] Enter Your Request Token Here : ");
data = kite.generate_session(request_tkn, api_secret=asecret)
kite.set_access_token(data["access_token"])

interval = "day"

savedata={}
def get_historical_data(instrument_token):
return kite.historical(instrument_token, from_date, to_date, interval)

trd_portfolio={5633: 'ACC',6401: 'ADANIENT',3861249: 'ADANIPORTS',2079745: 'AJANTPHARM'}

for token in trd_portfolio:
f= open(str(trd_portfolio[token])+".txt","w+")
from_date=datetime.date(2015,2,1)
to_date=from_date+tdelta
for x in range(1,45):
print(x)
print("\n",from_date)
print(to_date)
records = kite.historical_data(token, from_date, to_date, interval)
f.write(str(records))
for x in records:
print(x)
from_date=from_date+tdelta0
to_date=from_date+tdelta
print(token)
```

Comment: So where is the data?

Comment: data is getting downloaded from online paid subscription bu coming in a raw text format something like this image

Comment: don't use images, please provide a reproducable example [mcve] & [ask]

Comment: 'open':31427, 'high':31469, 'open':31427, 'high':31469, ,'open':3145427, 'high':31469, 'open':31427, 'high':31469, 'open':31427, 'high':314569

Comment: @sunil Add that to your post, and please fix the formatting. Stack Overflow is meant for **specific problems**. “It doesn’t work” isn’t an appropriate issue. What have you done to try to solve this, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

```
    data = """
'open':31427, 'high':31469, 'open':31427, 'high':31469, ,'open':3145427, 'high':31469, 'open':31427, 'high':31469, 'open':31427, 'high':314569"""
```

we just need to set the correct line break and delimitor in read csv

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),sep=':',lineterminator=',',header=None)
df.columns = ['status','price']
print(df)
        Status    Price
0   'open'    31427
1   'high'    31469
2   'open'    31427
3   'high'    31469
4   'open'  3145427
5   'high'    31469
6   'open'    31427
7   'high'    31469
8   'open'    31427
9   'high'   314569
```